# Connecting a raspberry pi to a second raspberry pi that is a network repeater

Tags: networking, wifi, bridge

I have two Raspberry Pis, one that is a wireless repeater, and another one that I just want to be connected through ethernet to the repeater and be connected. Is this possible to do?

Comment: If you already have the WiFi repeater setup and working then you already know how to configure a bridge,  you just need to bridge the 'incoming' wifi (the access point being repeated by your 2nd Wifi) to the Ethernet in addition to the outgoing Wifi.  Depending on how the first bridge is configured and routed will determine how difficult/possible this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to connect your RasPi to a second RasPi working as wireless repeater (access point). Just connect them with an ethernet cable. The wireless repeater must have routing enabled to forward traffic to its uplink. You can also bridge the ethernet interface with the local wireless network (not the uplink wireless connection). Here is a diagram as example to better understand what I mean:

```
          (dhcp)         bridge
           ╱    wifi    ┌──────┐
mobile-phone <~.~.~.~.> │(ap0) │               wifi            wan
                        │   br0│RPi(wlan0) <.~.~.~.~.> router <───> INTERNET
       RasPi <────────> |(eth0)│╲       ╲             ╱
           ╲    wired   └──────┘╱      (dhcp)    192.168.10.1
         (dhcp)          192.168.4.1

                       └─────────────────┘
                        wireless repeater
```

The bridge is optional, not necessary needed.